# HAPI FHIR - Data Model - Entity Relationship, does anyone have a link to an ERD model that is based on FHIR

Tags: entity-relationship, hl7-fhir, powerdesigner, hapi-fhir, erwin

I'm looking for an ERD based on the fundamental concepts of HAPI FHIR.  I have access to a number of Data Architect tools (Erwin / PowerDesigner) and wanted to know if anyone has a model they can perhaps share or point to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what you are asking for here. HAPI FHIR's model is FHIR, so it's all described on the FHIR spec homepage.

If you're looking for the database ERD, there are some here: https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_jpa/schema.html

Comment: I'm looking for an ERD for FHIR that can be leveraged via a Modelling tool like PowerDesigner.  Ideally it would be based on these entities:  http://hl7.org/fhir/resourcelist.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of such a thing existing. Might be worth asking on chat.fhir.org though.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking myself for an ERD since sometime. The most exhaustive that I have found is https://github.com/microsoft/Industry-Accelerator-Health/blob/master/documentation/Entity.Diagram.for.Dynamics.365.Electronic.Medical.Records.png

Comment: Link is now 404'd